# Passing a variable between HTML pages using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I begin with having a user input their name into a text field on the first html page and then click a button to move to a second html page.

How do I store the user's inputed name as a variable that can be referenced on a differnt html page?

**First HTML page**

```
<input type = "text" id = "name">

<button onclick = "sv(); window.location.href = 'second.html'">Submit now</button>
```

**JavaScript on First HTML page**

```
function sv() {
sessionStorage.setItem("theirname", document.getElementById("name").value);
 }
```

**Second HTML page**

```
 <p id="output"></p>
```

**JavaScript on Second HTML Page**

```
document.getElementById("output").value = sessionStorage.getItem("theirname");
```

Comment: A cookie, local storage, URL parameter, ...

Comment: try it with local storage , it will solve your issue

Comment: You can use `localStorage("theirname", document.getElementById("name").value);` and on you `second.html` page, use `localStorage.getItem("theirname")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works for me, which isn't much different than yours. Maybe it's how your importing your javascript?

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='./index.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "text" id = "name">
        <button onclick = "sv(); window.location.href = 'secondPage.html'">Submit now</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
function sv() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("theirname", document.getElementById("name").value);
}
```

**secondPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="output"></p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='./secondPage.js'></script>
    <!-- The script must come after and not in the head, or else document.getElementById will be null --> 
</html>
```

**secondPage.js**

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("theirname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can store the data into localStorage

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input'); 

setStorage = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('name', input.value);
}


//On your second HTML
getStorage = () => {
    localStorage.getItem('name');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="setStorage()">Go!</button>
```